# wpf enable the disabled button from different class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following button initialized as disabled that gets enabled when some event occurs:

```
<Button.Style> <!-- initially disabled-->
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

so if I run this code (click on some other button), then it gets enabled:

```
 private void Record_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Btn_Import.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

Another button that enables the first button is in the same form. However if I try creating an event with a button in a different window, it doesn't work. So if I do this in other window's class:

```
 private void New_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow xx = new MainWindow();
            xx.Btn_Import.IsEnabled = true;

        }
```

button indeed gets enabled which I can see in debugging mode, but it is actually not enabled when I hover the mouse over it in running app.

Please help

Comment: I don't think you want to be creating a new instance of your main window every time someone clicks a button. You would need a reference to the original main window in order to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In New_Click2 you have created a *new instance* of MainWindow. However, as far as I can see in the code you've provided, you've never *shown* this window instance:

```
xx.Show()
```

The MainWindow instance (xx) that you've created here may indeed have its import button enabled, but it's probably not the same instance that you're looking at on the screen. I suspect that if you add a line to show it you will see two instances of MainWindow. If so, the solution is that you need to pass the instance from one class to another, e.g. via a global instance, a parameter, injection, etc.

Comment: @LeMara Are you sure? I'm pretty sure all Windows in WPF are on the same (UI) thread, unless you explicitly create a new one with Dispatcher.Run. You would need to use a Dispatcher if you were called back from a new thread, but there are no new threads being kicked off here as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes sure you are right. I just made a test... and they are run in the same thread